# updateSiteAccountCredentials throws IllegalArgumentValueException

Tags: yodlee

I'm using the Yodlee REST API and try to update the credentials at a site. 
I'm doing the following sequence:

1. authenticate/coblogin
2. authenticate/login
3. SiteAccountManagement/updateSiteAccountCredentials

In 3 I pass:

```
cobSessionToken <cobSessionToken>
userSessionToken <userSessionToken> 
memSiteAccId  <memSiteAccId>
credentialFields.enclosedType com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
credentialFields[0].name  LOGIN
credentialFields[0].displayName User ID
credentialFields[0].valueMask LOGIN_FIELD
credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName  IF_LOGIN
credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier LOGIN
credentialFields[0].value <username>

credentialFields[1].name  PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].displayName Password
credentialFields[1].valueMask LOGIN_FIELD
credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName  IF_PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier PASSWORD
credentialFields[1].value <password>
```

All according to the API spec. 
But all I get back is:

```
"errorOccured": "true",
"exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException",
"refrenceCode": <referenceCode>,
"message": "Multiple exceptions encapsulated within: invoke getWrappedExceptions for details"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you try and do the same credential edit call for another site too.

If the call works for the other site, chances are it is an error related specifically to the site you're trying to edit above (and so, a ticket with Yodlee likely needs to be opened). HTH!